# How do you find duplicate strings in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with several stings, with some being duplicates. I need to pull out all the duplicate strings and append them into a new list. How can I do that?

```
list_i = ['a','b','a','c','a','c','g','w','s','c','d','a','b','c','a','e']
```

Comment: Did you try something? Please show what the specific problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `OrderedDict` to get a list without the duplicates then remove those from a copy of the original

```
from collections import OrderedDict

list_i = ['a','b','a','c','a','c','g','w','s','c','d','a','b','c','a','e']

non_dupes = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list_i))

dupes = list(list_i)
for d in non_dupes:
  dupes.remove(d)

print(dupes)
#['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
print(non_dupes)
#['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'w', 's', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated. Why not just `dups = list(filter(lambda x: l.count(x)>1, l))`

Comment: Well you are correct, I wasn't trying ot overcomplicate things, although with a counter they have the number of times a letter shows up

Comment: I edited, the list comprehension is better than a counter all day

Comment: Using a list comp like you suggested, keeps the duplicates, he wanted them to be removed and keep only the ones that are duplicates. I believe the counter method would have worked but the above is probably the best I can think of.

Comment: In that case `dups = list(set(filter(lambda x: l.count(x)>1, l)))`. However, he never said he wanted to remove the duplicates in the new list of duplicates (though I agree it's a reasonable assumption).